# OCaml: Using `try` and `with` for larger programs

Tags: exception, ocaml

Suppose you have a sequence of expressions that potentially raise an exception.  If it does, you want some long process to take place.  If it doesn't you want a different long process to take place.  In imperative languages you can usually do something like

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

but I can't seem to reproduce this in OCaml, because it seems like you can only check a single expression at a time for an exception.  I also don't see how you can use the value, if it exists, or do something else if it doesn't.

For a more concrete, if trivial example:  I have a function `list_max` that returns the max of a list if it's non-empty and raises an exception if it is empty.  Suppose I have a list and want to assert that its max is 4, but I'm wrong and it's really an empty list.  I can't seem to get the syntax right from explanations that I've found.  I've tried the following and many permutations on it:

```
try (list_max [])
with
| Failure s -> -1
| _ -> assert (list_max [] = 4);;
```

[Edit: rather than the contrived example above, perhaps one that makes more sense would be:  Suppose I want to unit test this `list_max` function.  I know I can do

```
assert ( (list_max [1;2;3] = 3 );;
```

But how would I test that `list_max` correctly throws an exception on an empty list?]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why not just do `assert (list_max [] = 4)`? What are you trying to achieve with `try` there?

Comment: @melpomene Would that not just throw an exception and halt the program?  If I were in an imperative language, what I would want is to try getting the `list_max` and do whatever I do with it--but if the program throws and exception, then move to the except block and execute the instructions there.

Comment: Yes, that's `try do_whatever with handle_exception_here`. I still don't see the issue. If you want concrete help, tell us what "*the instructions there*" should do.

Comment: @melpomene So in the example above, suppose I want to try to assert that the max of a list is 4, but if it doesn't exist, then return $-1$.  Perhaps an even better example, which I'll edit onto the post in a minute, would be: How could you do a unit test for `list_max`?

Comment: If you want to test that an exception was thrown, why not just `assert (try (list_max []; false) with Failure _ -> true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the assert in the try expression, as long as it raises an exception that you don't catch. Any other exception, such as `Assert_failure` in this case, will pass through.

```
try assert (list_max [] = 4) with
| Failure s -> -1
```

But `assert` returns `unit` so this will be a type error in any case.

An alternative is to use the [exception case in pattern matching](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#s%3Aexception-match):

```
match list_max [] with
| exception (Failure _) -> -1
| _ -> assert (list_max [] = 4)
```

(This still has a type error)

Finally, you might want to use the `option` or `result` type instead of exceptions, since they're much safer. The compiler won't let you just forget about the error conditions then. If `list_max` had returned an `option`, this would be:

```
match list_max [] with
| None -> -1
| Some _ -> assert (list_max [] = 4)
```

(Still has the type error though)

Comment: So ... everything here has an error, so what I'm trying to cannot be done?

Comment: Not as far as you've described it, no. What should the expression evaluate to if the assertion passes?